# 9-patch - Conservation of the height/width ratio of the non-stretchable area when scaling down

Tags: android, scale, android-cardview, nine-patch

I have the following 9 patch file as background of a cardview:
[image: 9-patch image]

To scale the image to the background I use the scale type "fitXY" on my ImageView :

```
          <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background_player_right_elo"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

It works well when the dimension of the card is greater than the image. However, in my case the height of the image is lower than the height of the image (45dp) and the result is distored :
[image]

I can reduce the size of the image but it gives a pixelated image.
I can't use standard image instead of 9-patch since the width of the card depends of the device screen width.

Is it possible to conserve the ratio height/width of the non-stretchable area when scaling down a 9-patch image?

Otherwise, is there another way of obtaining the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can mantain the central area unstretched and stretch only what's around it.

Comment: The central area is not marked as stretchable in the 9-patch file (if it is what you mean) but the height of the card is lower than the height of the image so it has to be stretched to fill the background of the card.

Comment: `The central area is not marked as stretchable in the 9-patch file` which is **OK**. `the height of the card is lower than the height of the image` which is **NOT OK**. You have to then provide a **smaller** 9 patch. the stretching is only guaranteed to work in the **expansion** sense, not in the **contraption** one.

Comment: Ok I understand that it is not guaranteed for 9-patch. However, if I use a smaller image, it is pixelated. Do you think there is another way of doing this? I don't know if I can superpose 2 ImageView (1 with the 9-patch of the background and 1 with the drawing which would not be a 9-patch).

Comment: I use 9 patches of different dimensions, depending on the screen density (which is also proprotional to the resolution - at least on phones). The stretchability only fills the gaps in different sizes the View may get on different displays (let's say for 480*800 or 480*854 resolutions on **hdpi** phone screens) in the same density slot. You're not guaranteed that the same png will work on ldpi as well as on xxxhdpi screens, which is very unlikely to happen.

Comment: I tried different image size and the height of the image has to be around 80 pixels not to be stretched on my phone which leads to a pixelated result. I should indeed use images of different size to fit any display. In that case, however, the result on my phone would be not stretched but still pixelated no?

Comment: If `the height of the image has to be around 80 pixels`, then make the height of the CardView big enough to contain it.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible answers depending on the constraints:

1. Reduce the size of the 9-patch image if the result is not too pixelated;
2. Increase the size of the CardView if you don't mind;
3. Otherwise, you can use two ImageView:

   - The first with scaleType "fitXY" that will contain a 9-patch image with the strechable background;
   - The second with scaleType "centerInside" that will only contain the logo  (which is not a 9-patch) and a transparent background.

Exemple:

```
        <!-- ImageView for the 9-patch background -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <!-- ImageView for the non 9-patch logo -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```